# Chrome not rendering math properly

Tags: web, html, mathjax

I use Chrome, (Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)), and lately I have been getting what I believe are math rendering errors like this:

[image]

What do I to remedy this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem with Chrome or is it with your own program which is producing output for Chrome to render?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's not my program, its just a website I am visiting. (https://www.investopedia.com/articles/etfs-mutual-funds/062716/fidelity-vs-vanguard-which-better-suited-you.asp)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially a bug report for a specific website that the OP visited.

Answer (score 1):

The source code probably reads `$7.95 for equity trades and $1...`. MathJax renders the data between the dollar signs.

I believe that you can display a literal dollar by putting it in a `span` element (`<span>$</span>`).

Comment: Not my site - a site I am visiting: (https://www.investopedia.com/articles/etfs-mutual-funds/062716/fidelity-vs-vanguard-which-better-suited-you.asp)

Comment: That site does not seem to use MathJax as far as I see. So forget about my answer :-).

But it renders perfectly in my Chrome 63.0.3239.132.

Comment: It sure looks like MathJax's output.  @TheGrapeBeyond, are you using a plugin or greasemonkey script that could be inserting MathJax into pages where it isn't loaded by default?